# Why the code dont enters in "if ($country == $request->country)"?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the method below to update the vat number of the user.

But when the user introduces some number in the VAT field and click in the "Update" button it shows "`Undefined variable: countryKey`".

It seems that the issue is that the code never enters in "                `if ($country == $request->country) {`
". But do you know why?

Do you know what can be the issue?

The HTML is like:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('user.updateGeneralInfo')}}" class="clearfix">
...
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
            <label for="vat">VAT:</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{$user->VAT}}" name="vat" class="form-control"
                   id="vat"
                    ">
        </div>
    </div>
...

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
        @if($user->country)
            <option selected="selected">{{$user->country}}</option>
        @endif
        @foreach($countries as $key => $country)
            <option value="{{$key}}">{{ $country}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

</form>
```

The `updateGeneralInfo()` is like:

```
public function updateGeneralInfo(Request $request){
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
        ];

        $customMessages = [
            'name.required' => 'The field name is mandatory.',
            'surname.required' => 'The field surname is mandatory.'
        ];

        if (isset($request->vat)) {

            $countries = Countries::all(); // get all countries using a package method
            // $country is equal to the current $country in the $countries array

            while ($country = current($countries)) {
            // if the $country is equal to the country selected by the user
                if ($country == $request->country) {
                    dd($country. '  ' .$request->country);

                  // the $countryKey is the key of the array in the $countries array. For example if the user selects the country "Germany" the $countryKey should be "DE"
                    $countryKey = (key($countries));
                }
                // if is not equal continue until it is equal
                next($countries);
            }

            $rules['vat'] = [
                function ($attr, $value, $fail) use ($request, $countryKey) {
                    if (!VatValidator::validateFormat($countryKey . $request->vat)) {
                        $fail('Please insert a valid VAT.');
                    }

                }];
        }

        $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);


        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->surname = $request->surname;

        $countries = Countries::all();

        if($request->country != $user->country){
            $user->country = $countries[$request->country];
        }

        $user->VAT = $request->vat;
        $user->save();

        Session::flash('general_success', 'Info updated with success.');

        return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]) . '#generalInfo');
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` tag around your `<input>`?

Comment: Yes, I update the question with that.

Comment: Is there an input for country in your form? The part you show only has an input `vat`.

Comment: I updated the question with that field.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping the declaration of `$countryKey` in an if block. If that block returns false, `$countryKey` won't be defined or have a value when you call it later and will error. Declare the variable outside of an if block and your issue should resolve.

Comment: Thanks, but also dont works correct like " $countryKey= ''; while ($country = current($countries)) {if ($country == $request->country) {dd($country. '  ' .$request->country); $countryKey = (key($countries));  } next($countries); }". The code goes dont enters in the if.

Comment: When you declare `$countryKey` outside of the if block you need to give it a sane default value.

Comment: But which value should be correct? Its not only necessary to create the variable?

Comment: Creating the variable will resolve the error you are seeing, nothing else. I don't know what `$countryKey` is or what a good default value would be for it. You can only know that as the author of this code.

Comment: Thanks, I add some comments to explain better.